# Need to merge a nested list into a single list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list `list1` (example) as shown below. It's the result of a function in my code.

Example:

```
list1 = ['2  String 2'] ['3  string 3']
```

Expected output from the above list is as below:

```
list1  = ['2  String 2', '3    string 3']
```

I'm stuck at this point.

Comment: Your input is a type error. Also: what have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: I'd say you want to flatten a list of lists

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a flat list out of list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists)

Comment: Hi, I am extracting the information from a pdf file. There is a list if strings in 2 pages. '2  String 2' is at the end of the first page and '3  string 3' is at the starting of 2nd page. I tried splitlines() function which generated this output ['2  String 2'] ['3  string 3'] . Trying to convert it into single list so that I can use it ahead.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your list looks like this (and not as in your example):

```
list1 = [['2  String 2'], ['3  string 3']]
```

Then simply:

```
list1 = [i[0] for i in list1]
```

Comment: Hi, I am extracting the information from a pdf file. There is a list of strings in 2 pages. '2  String 2' is at the end of the first page and '3  string 3' is at the starting of 2nd page. I tried splitlines() function which generated this output ['2  String 2'] ['3  string 3'] . Problem is the output of the splitlines. If input is like '[['2  String 2'], ['3  string 3']]' as you take in the example. Then it's easy to go ahead.

Comment: Can you tell me the output of `print(type(list1))` and `print(type(list1[0]))`?

Comment: Output for print(type(list1)) is :<class 'list'> <class 'list'>
Output for print(type(list1[0])) is :<class 'str'> <class 'str'>

Comment: Then you have nested lists and my answer should work. What is your output from my answer?